# Highlight a area with Google Maps JavaScript API v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, highlight

I want to highlight a area like on the image below which is taken from [Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/). Is this possible to accomplish with the current version of their API (v3)? If yes, how?

[image: google-maps-highlight]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know the vertices of the area and create a polygon based on them.

But dashed strokes currently are not supported by polygons, if you require to have a dashed stroke you must create a sequence of polylines with different stroke-colors based on the vertices.

A built-in method to highlight an area currently doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) It can be a lot of extra job to get the polygon on place for every place in the world. I hope that version 4 of their API will support this when it's released.

Answer (score 1):

You can automatically highlight an area with Google Maps Javascript API, here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Place ID Finder</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }

      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      #ggg
      {
          position: absolute;
          left:20%;
          top:5%;
      }

      .controls {
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 2px;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
        height: 29px;
        margin-left: 17px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        outline: none;
        padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        width: 400px;
      }

      .controls:focus {
        border-color: #4d90fe;
      }
      .title {
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      #infowindow-content {
        display: none;
      }
      #map #infowindow-content {
        display: inline;
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="display: none">
        <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Enter a location">
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="infowindow-content">
        <span id="place-name" class="title"></span><br>
        <strong>Place ID:</strong> <span id="place-id"></span><br>
        <span id="place-address"></span>
    </div>

    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 37.9989746, lng: 23.6413698},
          zoom: 11
        });

        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');

        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
        autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

        autocomplete.setFields(
            ['place_id', 'geometry', 'name', 'formatted_address']);

        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var infowindowContent = document.getElementById('infowindow-content');
        infowindow.setContent(infowindowContent);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map});

        marker.addListener('click', function() {
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });

        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
          infowindow.close();

          var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

          if (!place.geometry) {
            return;
          }

          if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
          } else {
            map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(17);
          }

          marker.setPlace({
            placeId: place.place_id,
            location: place.geometry.location,
          });

          marker.setVisible(true);

          infowindowContent.children['place-name'].textContent = place.name;
          infowindowContent.children['place-id'].textContent = place.place_id;
          infowindowContent.children['place-address'].textContent = place.formatted_address;
          infowindow.open(map, marker);

           var frame = document.getElementById("map");

           frame.innerHTML = '<iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=place_id:'.concat(place.place_id).concat('&key=XXXXXXX" allowfullscreen></iframe>');

           frame.innerHTML += '<p id="ggg"><button type="button" onclick="location.reload()">Try again!</button></p>';
        });
      }

    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXX&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>

</body>
</html>
```

You will need to replace API KEY with your API KEY. Try e.g."Nea Smyrni 171 21, Greece" in the input and then select the first drop down option and notice that it automatically highlights the area!

Comment: Hi is this works for you @pancy1 , as when we are trying .. we have one error .. 

Google Maps Platform rejected your request. This API project is not authorized to use this API.

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 () in google map

Comment: Hi, yes it works perfectly for me, just create and replace the API KEY with your API KEY.